# Display all but the last-child span in a map

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass

I am mapping through an Object in a ReactJS application. Between every Element of that mapping, I am adding a span with a simple carret `|`.

Here is the code:

```
  renderSecurityModes = (securityKey: string): JSX.Element => {
    const { user } = this.props;
    return (
      <div key={securityKey} className="users-overview-screen__no-last-child">
        {user && user.security && user.security[securityKey as SecurityMode] && (
          <Fragment>
            <span className="font-weight-medium mr-3 text-uppercase">{securityKey}</span>
            <span className="text-border-gray mx-3">|</span>
          </Fragment>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

THE PROBLEM:
I want the Item of the mapping to have the `|` between them, but the last one, I want to `display: none`

So, I added a little class to do just that. Display everything but the last child. But since the mapping takes place, it thinks every carret is the `last-child`:

Here is the scss:

```
.users-overview-screen__no-last-child {
  span:last-child {
      display: none;
  }
}
```

THE DOM-STRUCTURE:

```
<div class="display-flex>
  <span>Mapped Item 1</span>
  <div class=“users-overview-screen__no-last-child”>
    <span>|</span>
  </div>
  <span>Mapped Item 2</span>
  <div class=“users-overview-screen__no-last-child”>
    <span>|</span>
  </div>
    <span>Mapped Item 3</span>
  <div class=“users-overview-screen__no-last-child”>
    <span>|</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above scenario, I want the last `carret`, in Mapped Item 3, not to appear at all. But with my current scss, no carret appears.

Any ideas, on how to tell the class to only omit the absolutely last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be best option for you:-

```css
.users-overview-screen__no-last-child:last-child span:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the snippet i have updated the code.

```css
.display-flex div:last-child span {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="display-flex">
  <span>Mapped Item 1</span>
  <div class=“users-overview-screen__no-last-child”>
    <span>|</span>
  </div>
  <span>Mapped Item 2</span>
  <div class=“users-overview-screen__no-last-child”>
    <span>|</span>
  </div>
    <span>Mapped Item 3</span>
  <div class=“users-overview-screen__no-last-child”>
    <span>|</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn’t work. I will update the description to show how the DOM prints out the mapped elements..

Comment: added working snippet this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.display-flex div:last-child{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have different options, here are two of them:

```
.users-overview-screen__no-last-child {
    &:last-of-type { /* takes last element wrapping the item */
        &:last-child { /* removes the last element of the last item*/
            display: none;
        }
    }
}
```

However I think the **best option** would be to give a **border right** and **padding** to **each span item** and **remove the carrets or separators**, which is much clean and clear:

```css
.display-flex {
    display: flex;
}

span {
    padding: 0 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
    
span:last-of-type {
  border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="display-flex">
  <span>Mapped Item 1</span>
  <span>Mapped Item 2</span>
  <span>Mapped Item 3</span>
</div>
```

Above css in scss:

```
.display-flex {
    display: flex;

    span {
        padding: 0 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }

    &:last-of-type {
      border-right: none;
    }
}
```